# Open a png file and read it's hex values in C

Tags: c, png, hex

I am attempting to read a file with any filetype ending and determining from it's hex values if it is a PNG file.

So far I have tried on two different paths but none are working.

- With first I read first 16 characters since first 8 hex values determines if it has the right header. Then I try to seperate it and read is as hex value as it was presented in some other thread here.
- The other I just want to read first two values and determine if it is hex value to even see if it's working. It is not.

code:

```
int IS_PNG_FILE(char *name)
{
    FILE *dat = fopen (name, "rt");
    if (dat == NULL) return 1;
    int data_point;

    char buf[16], a[16];
    fgets(buf, 16, dat);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    int i, b;
    for (i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        sscanf(&buf[i], "%2x", &b);
        a[i] = b;
        i += 2;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);


    fscanf(dat, "%2x", &data_point);
    printf("%d\n", data_point);

    fclose(dat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fopen (name, "rt")`? try `"rb"` instead

Comment: It is still just returning maximal number or -2.

Comment: PNG files aren't text. The bytes in them are not hex "strings" at all, so `sscanf` won't do what you think, and this is not a technique that will be useful. You've already read in the first 16 bytes (good)-- you need to compare the value of those bytes in the value directly with the numbers you expect.

Comment: So, comething around strncmp(buf, "80504e470d0a1a0a")?

Comment: There's something you don't seem to understand about hexadecimal and binary. PNG files are not encoded as hexadecimal, they are encoded in a binary format. This binary format, when viewed by humans, is often converted to hexadecimal to make things easier to read, but they are actually the same. So "80504e470d0a1a0a" is not the hexadecimal value represented by that number, instead its that string of letters and numbers encoded with ANSI. If you are still confused, I'd be happy to help further.

Comment: How do I then transform from binary to a string encoded in ANSI, or what exactly I get with fgets function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to read the binary bytes from the file use `fread`:

The function fread() reads nmemb elements of data, each size bytes long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location given by ptr.

something like:

```
unsigned char head[8];

fread(head, sizeof(head), 1, dat);
```

you can check the return value to verify that 8 bytes were actually read.

then compare using memcmp

```
unsigned char signature[8] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A};

if (!memcmp(signature, head, 8))
{
    ...
}
```